# How to Test removing item from the list using Robotium on Android

Tags: java, android, testing, robotium

I have a list of items in my app. I would like to write a test case to remove an item from the list onLongClick. I used robotium method:

```
clickLongInList()
```

but it's not working properly how can I test removing items in a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you Long Click on item inside List,

i suppose that "there is menu exists that have option for delete"

if this menu exists then **clickLongOnText();** will open menu [which contains delete option]
             and **clickOnText("Delete");** this will delete your item from list.

i hope this will help you. Thanks.